# How do I dynamically update html in Rails and use helpers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to update the html of a div using jQuery in Rails. And I want to use helpers.

For instance, let's say I am trying to put an image in the div. Here is what I am doing in js file:

```
// Update the html content of #div
// I am using a helper, img_tag

$("#div").html("<%= img_tag('some_image.png') %><br> + 'some message'"
```

But the helper does not create img tag. Instead, it is displayed in the div as a string.

```
i.e.
// Content of the div as a result:

<%= img_tag('some_image.png') %><br> some message
```

When I manually type the html tag, it works.

```
i.e.
$("#div").html("<img src="assets/images/some_image.png" alt="img"><br>
 + 'some message'"
```

But I want to know how I can use helpers in this case, because I am also trying to use other helpers such as link_to.

Comment: Are you sure you have the png image you want in your app/assets/images folder?

Comment: @JoelL Hmmm.. Yes, I have it in the app/assets/images folder. Not only can I not use img_tag, but also I cannot use link_to, etc.

Comment: What problem are you getting with the link_to tag?

Comment: @JoelL the helpers simply get displayed as texts, and not generate html tags as they should.

Comment: @JoelL Thanks, but the helpers are still displayed as texts.

Comment: Where do you put the above JS code?

Comment: @charinten I put it in apps/assets/javascripts as a .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues to consider:

---

**JS**

Firstly, you need to consider the JS that you're trying to use.

By definition, **standard [JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) cannot use rails helpers**. Reason is that JS is a "front-end" / "client-side" language, which will only work *after* a page has loaded. Indeed, JS tends to only work with the ["DOM" (Document Object Model)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model):

> JavaScript (JS; English pronunciation: /'jɑvəˌskrɪpt/) is a dynamic
>   computer programming language. It is most commonly used as part of
>   web browsers, whose implementations allow client-side scripts to
>   interact with the user, control the browser, communicate
>   asynchronously, and alter the document content that is displayed.
>   It is also being used in server-side network programming (with
>   Node.js), game development and the creation of desktop and mobile
>   applications.

The bottom line is that **Javascript will only load up on the client-side part of your application**. Since Ruby / Rails is *server* side, equivocal to the likes of PHP, your JS will therefore not be able to process the Rails helpers in the traditional flow you have.

The only way to get around this is to combine your JS with Rails' loading mechanisms somehow. This can either be done with [`ajax`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) (to pull from the server), or render your js with Rails (not sure how)

---

**Fix**

I believe that you can use [preprocessing with Rails JS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing), which means that, like `erb`, you'll be able to call Rails helpers within your javascript files:

> The same applies to a JavaScript file -
>   app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee.erb is processed as ERB,
>   then CoffeeScript, and served as JavaScript.
>
> Keep in mind the order of these preprocessors is important. For
>   example, if you called your JavaScript file
>   app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.erb.coffee then it would be
>   processed with the CoffeeScript interpreter first, which wouldn't
>   understand ERB and therefore you would run into problems.

This means that if you wanted to do what you're doing, you'll need to **append preprocessors** to ensure it can call the Rails helpers:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
var loaded = function(){
   $("#div").html("<%=j image_tag('some_image.png') %><br> + 'some message'"
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", loaded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript file must have a .erb extension to use embedded ruby.